# Virtual hosts not working with install of macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost, macos-sierra

I recently updated my work machine to macOS Sierra and now none of my virtual host configurations are working. I need to reconfigure all of these which is a huge pain.

I am wondering - is it normal for this to happen? Is there a way to prevent this from happening in the future when I update my operating system?

Additionally, it appears that my virtual host configuration is not working. Please see below.

I have edited `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to include:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin lbanach@splashworldwide.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/splashnw/Sites/tm-charts"
ServerName tm-charts.dev
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/tm-charts.dev-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/tm-charts.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And, my `/etc/hosts` file has:

```
127.0.0.1 tm-charts.dev
```

When I navigate to tm-charts.dev in my browser, there is simply a message: "It works!" Not my project that I originally saw at that URL prior to installing macOS Sierra.

Can you tell me what is going wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: What IP do you get if you `ping tm-charts.dev`?

Comment: @capsule If I ping, I get this content:

`64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms` etc.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure it goes to 127.0.01 and the hosts file is actually OK. Could you try adding `::1             localhost` to it? The fact you still get to the default apache vhost proves Apache still listen on IPv4, so the `*` vhost base should be any IP, v4 or v6, but who knows.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you updated to macOS it overwrote your "**httpd.conf**" file in the /etc/apache2/ folder. It also overwrote your "**http-vhost.conf**" file as well in the /etc/apache2/extra folder.

You need to see if you have a backup file in those directories to uncomment the lines or use this as an example to help restore your settings: http://digitalshore.io/local-web-development-environment-apache-macos-sierra-10-12/

Check both the "**/etc/apache2**" and "**/etc/apache2/extra**" folder for the **http-conf~previous** and **http-vhost.conf~previous** files to put your previous settings back

When you are done be sure to run **sudo apachectl restart** for the new settings to take effect.

Comment: I'm seeing httpd.conf.pre-update and httpd.conf~previous. Should I be copying the entire contents of httpdconf~previous into the main httpd.conf file? If so how can I replace the entire contents of httpd.conf and http-vhost.conf? I tried with an editor without luck.

Comment: I did restarted apachectl and problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Also after you are done with the instructions provided by @chris-holcomb , do the following:

edit the file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

uncomment line 160:

```
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

to

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

uncomment line 509:

```
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

to

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

as a precaution, clear your dns cache with the following command using terminal:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Finally, restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Source: [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255463/210589)